# How do I stream invocations of dependent TestNG methods across test instances?

Tags: testng

I am using TestNG [Factory](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/annotations/Factory.html) to create multiple test instances of a test class. The test class has multiple test methods, each of which needs to be executed serially (i.e. each test method is dependent on the previous test method in the test class).

When I run my test suite containing multiple test instances of my test class created via my factory method all of the first test methods run first, then all of the second test methods, then all of the third test methods, and so forth.

What I want instead is for all of the test methods in each test instance to finish as soon as possible. i.e. The first test method in the first test instance runs, then its second test method, and so forth through its Nth test method and then the second test instance starts.

I've tried using [`dependsOnMethods`](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/annotations/Test.html#dependsOnMethods--) as well as [`priority`](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/annotations/Test.html#priority--) but I can't seem to get the behavior I want.

How do I stream invocations of dependent TestNG methods across test instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependencies-with-annotations):

> By default, dependent methods are grouped by class. For example, if
>   method `b()` depends on method `a()` and you have several instances of
>   the class that contains these methods (because of a factory of a data
>   provider), then the invocation order will be as follows:
>
> ```
> a(1)
> a(2)
> b(2)
> b(2)
> ```
>
> TestNG will not run `b()` until all the instances have invoked their
>   `a()` method. This behavior might not be desirable in certain
>   scenarios, such as for example testing a sign in and sign out of a web
>   browser for various countries. In such a case, you would like the
>   following ordering:
>
> ```
> signIn("us")
> signOut("us")
> signIn("uk")
> signOut("uk")
> ```
>
> For this ordering, you can use the XML attribute `group-by-instances`.
>   This attribute is valid either on `<suite>` or `<test>`: view
>   sourceprint?
>
> ```
>   <suite name="Factory" group-by-instances="true">
> or
>   <test name="Factory" group-by-instances="true">
> ```

Comment: Right there in front of me. Thank you! I even recall now reading this months (years?) ago and thinking, "I'm not sure when I'd ever use that but that's cool." Now I know. :-)

Comment: Is there a way to run grouped instances in parallel?

Comment: i.e. 10 instances run in parallel where each method within the instance runs sequential in the same thread while not waiting on other instances' progress.

Comment: parallel="instances",  but it may not work: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/labels/Feature%3A%20parallel

Comment: Ah, thank you. That was what I was trying and I had not yet looked at the open issues.

Comment: I didn't find an exact match between existing issues and yours. So, please comment the one which matches or open a new one.